# Using MinionPro for the main font and Fontspec for the monospaced font

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I am using `Minion Pro` for my document's main font and would like to use Consolas for my code listings.

I know that I can set the monospace font using `fontspec` and `setmonofont`, but it seems I cannot use `fontspec` in conjunction with the `MinionPro` and `MnSymbol` packages that I use to set my document's main font.

I do not want to use `fontspec` to set my main font, since headings in all-caps and small-caps do not render as nicely as with the `MinionPro` package.

**My question**: Is there a way I can use the `MinionPro` package to set my main font and tell `fontspec` to 'ignore' the main font and just set the monofont. Else, is there another way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest you load `MinionPro` with `onlymath` option. As far as I understand it, `MnSymbol` is mainly used for math.

Use `\setmainfont` of `fontspec` to set `Minion Pro` As the math font. The problem with all caps and small caps is because `MinionPro` optimized the spacing while `fontspec` won't do it for you automatically. But the solution is simple, use `\addfontfeatures{WordSpace=...}` feature of `fontspec`. Also `Kerning=Uppercase` will enable the `cpsp` opentype feature though I don't find its space is enough for all caps title.

Indeed I used `MinionPro` package for quite a long time. But the only reason stopped me for switching to `fontspec` before is the lack of support of microtype in `xetex`. Now I use `fontspec` and `LuaTeX` exclusively. This is a better solution than `MininonPro` since you can access features like `case` easily, which will select right punctuations when typeset in all caps. And much more.

For `Minion Pro` font, however, I found that it has a few problems with `fontspec`. At least on my Mac, there are issues for `fontspec` to select correct weight and optical sizes. See https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/105.

In my case the `medium` weight cause `fontspec` or `luatex` confused. So I added the following to `otfl-blacklist.cnf`.

```
MinionPro-Medium.otf
MinionPro-MediumCapt.otf
MinionPro-MediumSubh.otf
MinionPro-MediumDisp.otf
```

And used the following to setup my fonts to get correct optical size.

```
\setmainfont[
SizeFeatures = {
  {Size =     -8.41, OpticalSize = 8},
  {Size = 8.41-13.1, OpticalSize = 11},
  {Size = 13.1-20.0, OpticalSize = 19},
  {Size = 20.0-,     OpticalSize = 72}},
Ligatures          = {Required, Common, Contextual, TeX},
Numbers            = {OldStyle, Proportional},
RawFeature         = {expansion  = default},
UprightFeatures    = {RawFeature = {protrusion = mnr}},
BoldFeatures       = {RawFeature = {protrusion = mnrb}},
ItalicFeatures     = {RawFeature = {protrusion = mni}},
BoldItalicFeatures = {RawFeature = {protrusion = mnib}}
]{Minion Pro}
```

where `mnr`, `mnrb`, etc are protrusion settings I wrote based on `MinionPro` package's

Answer (score 3):

You can try the **mathspec** package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Minion Pro}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setmonofont{Inconsolata}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}

a$\alpha\sum b=c$\texttt{aaa}
\end{document}
```

I didn't do extensive tests, however.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any Problem

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

Mininpro \textsf{Myriad Pro} \texttt{Consolas}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily\small]
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```