# How to display the font size in use in the final output

Tags: fonts, luatex

How can I display the font size in use at a particular point of the document.

For example, in the following code, I produced a PDF file showing the fonts actually used for each shape and size,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{mred} {cmyk}{0,1,1,0.6}
\definecolor{mblue}{cmyk}{1,1,0,0.2}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\long\def\testfont{
  \foreach \size in
  {normalsize, Large, Huge}
  {\csname\size\endcsname\testshape}}

\long\def\testshape{
  \vskip\baselineskip
  \csname\size\endcsname\size
  \vskip\baselineskip
  \foreach \shape in {up, it, sc, bf}
  {\par\csname text\shape\endcsname
    {
      \textcolor{mred}{\directlua{tex.print(font.fonts[font.current()].fullname)}}
      \textcolor{mblue}{\shape}
    }}
  \vskip\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \flushleft
  \rmfamily\testfont\vfill
\end{document}
```

This will produce the following. (as you see `fontspec` or `luaotfload` does not select correct optical fonts, see my answer for [Using MinionPro for the main font and Fontspec for the monospaced font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20260/using-minionpro-for-the-main-font-and-fontspec-for-the-monospaced-font/20266#20266) of how to workaround this)

My question is that, instead of print "normalize", "Large", "Huge", I would like to print things like "10pt" or just "10", so I can see the actual font size, just like in this example I can see the actual fonts used.

I know this can be done with things like Acrobat. But in that way, one has to click numerous 
times of his mouse to examine the fonts. I would prefer a more automatically way, similar to the way I print the fonts names in the example.

Many thanks in advance.

[image: fonttest]

Comment: How do you know that the font size is a length and not a unitless number? Moreover, how do you know that the correct unit after `\f@size` is `pt`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know whether I understand you question right. Here is my interpretation ;-)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
orig: \f@size

\verb+\small+ \small \f@size

\verb+\normalsize+ \normalsize \f@size

\verb+\large+ \large \f@size

\verb+\Huge+ \Huge \f@size
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

`\f@size` is the internal macro in LaTeX2e NFSS. If a font is not specified through NFSS, this may fail. To know the size of LaTeX commands like `\large`, you can read [`classes`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/classes.pdf) document.

Furthermore, you don't need to use direct Lua code to get the font name.

Here is the low-level method to show the font size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luaotfload}
\font\1="TeX Gyre Termes"
\begin{document}

\fontname\font\ at \the\fontdimen6\font
% cmr10 at 10.00002pt

\1
\fontname\font\ at \the\fontdimen6\font
% TeX Gyre Termes at 10.0pt
\end{document}
```

`\fontdimen6` is the length of `1em`. `\font` after `\fontname` and `\fontdimen` means current font. See Chapter 4 of *[TeX by Topic](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf)* for more explanations.

Comment: I know \fontname, but it won't work very well. For example it will give the following while loading fonts with `fontspec` `MinionPro/S=8:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+liga;+tlig;+trep;+onum;+pnum;expansion = default;protrusion = mnr; at 5.0pt`. It is much better to have `Minion Pro Caption` than `MinionPro/S=8`

Answer (score 2):

`font.fonts[font.current()].size` gives the size in *scaled points*. Dividing by 65536 wil give the size in pts.