# font size selection how multiple of \normalsize

Tags: fontsize

is possible make a command like this?

```
\fontsize{2\normalsize}{2\normalsize}\selectfont
```

Answer (score 4):

Your request isn't directly possible. The command `\normalsize` isn't a dimension, but a command that performs several actions.

Of course the command `\normalsize` depends on the font size. But it also depends on the class. The standard classes define the command related to the selected font size in the files `size1X.clo`. The `X` stands for

```
0 => 10pt
1 => 11pt
2 => 12pt
```

In the file `size10.clo` `\normalsize` is defined as

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
```

where `\@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt` means:

```
 \def\@xpt{10}
 \def\@xipt{10.95}
 \def\@xiipt{12}

\def\@setfontsize#1#2#3{\@nomath#1%
    \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
      \let\@currsize#1%
    \fi
    \fontsize{#2}{#3}\selectfont}
```

To detect the current font size see [How to display the font size in use in the final output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20451/how-to-display-the-font-size-in-use-in-the-final-output/20452#20452)

There you can find that the command `\f@size` represent the current font size. To save the standard font size use:

```
\edef\savefontsize{\f@size}
```

I can imagine the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\normalsize
\xdef\doublesize{\noexpand\fontsize{\noexpand\numexpr2*\f@size\noexpand\relax pt}{\noexpand\dimexpr\f@baselineskip+\f@baselineskip\noexpand\relax}\noexpand\selectfont}
\endgroup


\begin{document}
Text Text

\doublesize Text Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: The example wouldn't work for 11pt size, as `\f@size` would expand to 10.95, which isn't legal in `\numexpr`; probably `\xdef\doublesize{\noexpand\fontsize{\the\dimexpr2\dimexpr\f@size pt}{\the\dimexpr2\dimexpr\f@baselineskip}\noexpand\selectfont}` is better.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the `relsize` package, it does exactly what you request. A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext,relsize}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\textscale{2}{\blindtext\par}
{\relscale{2}\blindtext}\par}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\relscale` takes just one argument, the scale factor. If you want to limit the effect put the `\relscale` within a group, e.g. `{\relscale{2}\blindtext}`.

Answer (score 0):

it is set relative to the current fontsize:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgpagella}

\makeatletter
\def\setFS#1{\@tempdima=\f@size pt\fontsize{#1\@tempdima}{\dimexpr #1\@tempdima+2pt}\selectfont}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
foo \setFS{1.5}bar \setFS{2}baz \normalsize
foobar

\end{document}
```

[image]