# How to know the font size and page layout from a source LaTeX file

Tags: pdftex, templates, msword, latex-to-word

I have a deadline to submit a manuscript to a journal for review. I have written my paper in Word 2013. However, the journal does not provide a Word template, but only a LaTeX template. I don't want to convert all equations and details from Word to LaTeX. I would like to know how to determine the font size and page layout from from the journal's LaTeX template, which can downloaded at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle

Currently, I just open the PDF file from that journal and convert it to Word to see the page layout. However, it did not show correct information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For font, you can use the `\f@size` macro ([see this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20451/how-to-display-the-font-size-in-use-in-the-final-output)).
For the layout, you can use the `layout` package (just add `\usepackage{layout}` to the preamble) and the command `\layout` after `\begin{document}`. This is what I got when I used this with the `el­sar­ti­cle-tem­plate-harv.tex` template.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. What is text font size ? Do you have word template file? I am very thankful to you.

Comment: @user3051460 You are welcome! Sorry I don't have a Word template. I just downloaded the file from your link and used ShareLaTeX to get the layout.

Comment: Yes sir. Could you see help me the font size, too? I think they use font 10 for text body and title as 14, please check help me

Comment: @user3051460 I updated the answer with font info.