# Minion Pro + fontspec = very strange kerning

Tags: xetex, fontspec, minionpro

I have an MWE, mostly derived from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20266/174314):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    UprightFeatures={
        SizeFeatures={
            {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-Capt},
            {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-Regular},
            {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-Subh},
            {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-Disp}
        },
    },
    BoldFeatures={
        SizeFeatures={
            {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-BoldCapt},
            {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-Bold},
            {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-BoldSubh},
            {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-BoldDisp}
        },
    },
    ItalicFeatures={
        SizeFeatures={
            {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-ItCapt},
            {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-It},
            {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-ItSubh},
            {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-ItDisp}
        },
    },
    BoldItalicFeatures={
        SizeFeatures={
            {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-BoldItCapt},
            {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-BoldIt},
            {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-BoldItSubh},
            {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-BoldItDisp}
        },
    },
    Ligatures          = {Required, Common, Contextual, TeX},
    Numbers            = {OldStyle, Proportional},
    RawFeature         = {expansion  = default},
    UprightFeatures    = {RawFeature = {protrusion = mnr}},
    BoldFeatures       = {RawFeature = {protrusion = mnrb}},
    ItalicFeatures     = {RawFeature = {protrusion = mni}},
    BoldItalicFeatures = {RawFeature = {protrusion = mnib}}
]{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}
\section{What the heck is going on?}
\end{document}
```

And the resultant output:
[image]

As the image so clearly asks, what is going on, and how can I fix it? I have a commercial, licensed version of Minion Pro from Adobe Font Folio, and the `pdflatex` package `MinionPro` works fine.

XeTeX also throws several dozen warnings:

```
Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Required, Common,
(fontspec)                Contextual, TeX' (rlig) not available for font
(fontspec)                'Minion Pro' with script 'CustomDefault' and
(fontspec)                language 'Default'.


Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Required, Common,
(fontspec)                Contextual, TeX' (clig) not available for font
(fontspec)                'Minion Pro' with script 'CustomDefault' and
(fontspec)                language 'Default'.


Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Required, Common,
(fontspec)                Contextual, TeX' (rlig) not available for font
(fontspec)                'MinionPro-Capt' with script 'CustomDefault' and
(fontspec)                language 'Default'.


Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Required, Common,
(fontspec)                Contextual, TeX' (liga) not available for font
(fontspec)                'MinionPro-Capt' with script 'CustomDefault' and
(fontspec)                language 'Default'.


Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Required, Common,
(fontspec)                Contextual, TeX' (clig) not available for font
(fontspec)                'MinionPro-Capt' with script 'CustomDefault' and
(fontspec)                language 'Default'.


Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Numbers=Lowercase' (onum) not
(fontspec)                available for font 'MinionPro-Capt' with script
(fontspec)                'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.


Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Numbers=Lowercase' (pnum) not
(fontspec)                available for font 'MinionPro-Capt' with script
(fontspec)                'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.


Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Required, Common,
(fontspec)                Contextual, TeX' (rlig) not available for font
(fontspec)                'MinionPro-Regular' with script 'CustomDefault' and
(fontspec)                language 'Default'.

...
```

Again, Minion Pro is one of Adobe's flagship typefaces, so I am quite certain it supports all the ligature types. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what happens with lualatex?

Comment: Okay, it compiles fine with `lualatex`, but the warnings are still there.

Comment: I get the right result both with xelatex and lualatex. Plus a lot of warnings from `fontspec`

Comment: In both cases the warnings  disappear commenting  `Ligatures  = {Required, common, Contextual, TeX},` because `Contextual, TeX' (rlig) not available for font` and similar.

Comment: you could try to  change the script, but I don't have the fonts so I can't try. Regarding the xelatex problem: check if you have more than one version of the font, xelatex doesn't like that much.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, using LuaLaTeX is the workaround I am using for now. That said, I am still very curious as to why this happens (only with XeTeX), and would like to explore this.

Comment: @SimonDispa, thanks for that. I wonder why adding that line removes the warnings, but retains the ligatures...